# Check if KinectRegion is ideal

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I am creating a Kinect WPF application how can i check if KinectRegion is ideal or not. Means if there is no user interacting so that after 7sec of ideal I should perform some action. There is no sample. Please if someone can provide a sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the InteractionGallery-WPF sample from the [Developer Toolkit v1.8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindowsdev/downloads.aspx). It does exactly what you want.